# LEFT JOIN to show NULL rows + WHERE

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, left-join

I have two tables, one which contains unique names (bill_datatypes), and another one which expresses that these names are connected to some subcategories (one name can be connected to more categories as well).

**The first table (relevant part):**
[image: The first table (relevant part)]

**The second table (relevant part):**
[image: The second table (relevant part)]

I would like to select all the names which are not connected to a specific subcategory yet. This means that the names might be mentioned in the connecting table but connected to a different subcategory.

I have solved the problem with the following subquery:

```
SELECT T1.name
FROM bill_datatype T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (

SELECT T2.bill_datatype_id
FROM obligatory_field T2
WHERE T2.bill_datatype_id = T1.id AND T2.bill_sub_category_id = 1

)
```

This solution seems to work well, but this way I can not have any data from the second table, which might be needed in the future.

Do you have any suggestions on how to solve the problem with a LEFT JOIN? (The WHERE clause on the subcategory made it too challenging for me.)

Thank you for your help also in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From how I understand your question, I think this query will achieve what you want:

```
SELECT T1.name
FROM bill_datatype T1
LEFT JOIN obligatory_field T2
ON T2.bill_datatype_id = T1.id AND T2.bill_sub_category_id = 1
WHERE T2.bill_datatype_id IS NULL
```

The `WHERE` condition on the `JOIN'ed` table will give you only the names from `T1` which have no `bill_sub_category_id` or their `bill_sub_category_id` is not 1.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9a0fe/5)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct T1.name
FROM 
bill_datatype T1 
right join
(

SELECT T2.bill_datatype_id
FROM obligatory_field T2
WHERE  T2.bill_sub_category_id = 1

) 
as T3
on T1.id != T3.bill_datatype_id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d4f616/18

Comment: This shows exactly the lines which are connected to the sub_category #1. I would need all those which are NOT connected to this sub_category.

Comment: Sorry but, I still don't think this solves it. I would need all the rows from table 1 one which are not mentioned with a specific sub_category_id (e.g. 1) in the table 2.

Comment: can you chat with me more details

Comment: can you please check this link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/963f29/2 is that ok for you as a output or please see and share what will be output from here

Comment: I edited the schema and added my working subquery solution in order to show the desired output http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d4f616/2 thanks for the help!

Comment: your query shows only name 2,name 3,name 5 but not name 1 . does it required to show name 1 or not?

Comment: select distinct T1.name
FROM bill_datatype T1
left join obligatory_field T2
on T2.bill_datatype_id = T1.id
order by T1.name  this query will show  name 1
name 2
name 3
name 5

Comment: my query shows what I want to be shown. name 1 should not be shown, because it has a relation with sub_category_id = 1.

Comment: On the test data it is good, but on my real database it is still not perfect. I'm checking now what could it be.